# How to sort this given numpy array by the first field of its rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sorting, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array like so:

```
data = np.array([
     (3, 730, 578, 696, 655),
     (1, 968, 728, 798, 809),
     (4, 882, 627, 962, 722),
     (9, 450, 462, 483, 487),
     (8, 435, 433, 449, 453),
     (7, 464, 434, 446, 436)], dtype=[('a', np.int), ('b', np.int), ('c', np.int), ('d', np.int), ('e', np.int)])
```

The shape is `(6,)`

I'd like to sort the rows by that first field containing the small int, so that I end up with:

```
[(1, 730, 578, 696, 655)
 (3, 968, 728, 798, 809)
 (4, 882, 627, 962, 722)
 (7, 450, 462, 483, 487)
 (8, 435, 433, 449, 453)
 (9, 464, 434, 446, 436)]
```

The array is called `data`. I tried this, which I have seen in some blog post:

```
data[data[:].argsort()]
```

But it doesn't really does anything to this array - remains sorted the same as when I created it.

How can I do this?

Comment: what's `data` shape and dtype?  Did you check parts of the expression to determine exactly which indexing operation gave the problem?

Comment: @hpaulj I will update the question with the array details, thanks!

Comment: Ah... nevermind, I found the issue... I was not assigning the result to `data`, like this: `data = data[data[:].argsort()]`

Now its working as intended

Comment: `data['a'].argsort()` to sort on just one field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah... silly mistake.. I was not assigning the result to data as I should. Correcting to do:

```
data = data[data[:].argsort()]
```

solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To sort a structured array in-place, by a given column, pass the column
name in *sort* parameter.

So in your case you can run:

```
data.sort(order='a')
```

When you print *data* again, you will get:

```
array([(1, 968, 728, 798, 809), (3, 730, 578, 696, 655),
       (4, 882, 627, 962, 722), (7, 464, 434, 446, 436),
       (8, 435, 433, 449, 453), (9, 450, 462, 483, 487)],
      dtype=[('a', '<i4'), ('b', '<i4'), ('c', '<i4'), ('d', '<i4'), ('e', '<i4')])
```